# Unable to load Web Application project due to its configuration

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I've a problem with loading Web Application project in VS2013. This project depends on IIS Express, but I wouldn't install IIS Express because I already installed IIS.

What I can edit in .csproj file to load this project? I've tried to set  to false, but it's wouldn't help me to solve problem.

Thank you for advice.

Upd.1: Also, I cannot create new web projects - VS tell me same things.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Happened to me too. My workaround:

1. Right-click the (failed-to-load) project => edit web.csproj
2. Find the line `<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>`, and change it to `false`.
3. Save, close, reload project.

Result - different error:

> The Web Application Project web is configured to use IIS.  To access local IIS Web sites, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account. In addition, you must install the following IIS components:
>
> ASP.NET

So:

1. Edit again, change `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` to `false`
2. Save, close, reload project.

Result - Great Success!

Comment: I had to do this in the ProjectName.csproj.user file, because I have "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" cleared in the project. Just deleting the .user file did not work.

Comment: Great success unless you actually don't want to use IIS, but were wanting it to use IIS Express.  In my case it was changing settings stored in the csproj (on the insistance of others in the team) from IISExpress to IIS.  Deleting the user file as recommended in the answer below was the solution.

Answer (score 32):

Try to delete user config file "ProjectName.csproj.user" then reload project.

> [VS 2012 can't load project which uses IIS with custom binding host - thinks it's using IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657607/vs-2012-cant-load-project-which-uses-iis-with-custom-binding-host-thinks-its#answer-27700371)

Comment: My issue was not related to IIS Express but pointing to IIS. The delete worked, thanks.

Comment: This file contains a copy of the settings referenced in Jonathan's answer.  This file can get out of sync if you switch the .csproj to IIS, then undo the file in git.  The .csproj still wants to use IIS but the .csproj wants to use IIS express.

Comment: This happens when you have changed the "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" from disabled to enabled and the settings for the server are in both the user file and the csproj file and those settings conflict.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today. Changing "UseIIS" to false allowed to load project, but not use IIS. After some tests I've found the cause of the problem:

On previous CheckIn to VSS somehow the UAC (user account control) was switched on. So actually there were two alternatives: (i) Always use "Run as administrator" ; (ii) switch UAC off.
I prefer (ii).

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom host file setup up with foo.localhost -> localhost bound on both ports for HTTP/HTTPS

checking on something i removed the host header for the binding on port 80.
once reloading solution is when everything started crashing.

found a really old post that reminded me that i removed that host name from the binding.

adding foo.localhost header back to the binding and all my projects started reloading.

Answer (score -2):

If nothing works, try removing following two lines from `.csproj` file. (always worked for me)

```
<ProjectGuid>{3AA499DF-4A65-43B7-8965-D08A4C811834}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Before I remove a project guid, I would like to understand what it is I'm removing first. If it works, why? If unknown...this is guessing and unsure answers are likely to get me into more trouble. Sorry.