# Cannot open new project or old project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012

[image]

Recently I have installed VS 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio. When I try to open the New Project, I'm getting this error:

> Web application projects are currently configured to use IIS Express. To switch back to using the Visual Studio Development server, change the development server option under the Projects and Solutions/Web Projects category of the Tools/Options menu. Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:
>   Filename: redirection.config
>   Error: Cannot read configuration file

I was Search about that issue. But  the given solution doesn't fix my problem.
I have tried

1. Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off... inside that, we had to select Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatibility -> IIS Metabse and IIS 6 configuration compatibility."
2. true replace it with the string True.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Did you do a google search for that error.. if not here you can check this link out for how to resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161151/unable-to-load-web-application-project-due-to-its-configuration

Comment: Try editing the CSproject file in notepad and set UseIISExpress to false

Comment: What if you try what has been suggested [here]? [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897726/iisexpress-8-cannot-read-configuration-file-redirection-config

Comment: I already checked your suggested link and tried.. The problem was not fixed. more over that link for opening existing project. I trying to open new Project file @MethodMan

Comment: I tried for old project    
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Reinsurance</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Reinsurance</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>.. Replaced to false. Not working and where can i get CSproject file for New Project @Rex

Comment: Moved three files from 
`
    C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer

to

    %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config` . Same Problem

Comment: Ok. Set UseIISExpress = false in both  .csproj and csproj.user files. Sometime suer file overrides the other one.