# Symbol status showing "Skipped Loading" for dll in modules window?

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

I've recently upgraded some solution(s) to Visual studio 2013. All went OK apart from one which now generates the:

> Symbol for the modules 'name' were not loaded.

...error every time I run it.

When I look in the modules debug window I can see against the dll (It's a web service dll)

```
Name           Path                       Optimised    User Code    Symbol Status
dllName.dll    Tempoary ASP.Net...etc.    Yes          No           Skipped Loading...
```

If I look in the `\bin` I see the `dll` and it's coresponding `.pdb`  file.

Checking the build menu for the project I can see `Debug Info: full`.

Cut a long story short everything looks fine to me except that it's not loading any symbols.

Any idea what I'm missing?

### Update

It looks like if I run my solution though IIS express the issue goes away. But running though IIS (8) I still have this problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After painfully comparing two project files, one that worked and one that didn't I noticed that the proj that worked had:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>

  <!-- This works -->
     <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <!----------------------->

  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Where as my one had

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>

  <!-- This DOESN'T -->
     <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <!----------------------->

  <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>

</PropertyGroup>
```

By setting the `<Optimize>` property to `false` all issues went away.

This [answer also seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550532/542251) as the `.csproj.user` file can be out of sync, I deleted it.

Comment: I had the same problems when I run azure project in emulator and your suggestion to delete  `.csproj.user` worked perfectly.

Comment: You can still have this problem if you do not have an `optimize` element at all; apparently it defaults to true. Once I added `<Optimize>false</Optimize>` to my csproj, my symbols started properly loading.

Comment: By default the 'Debug' configuration of the build has Optimize to false, and the Release has true. In my case I was simply referencing the Release build of my project, so the symbols were not loaded