# Unable to debug VS2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

I am having trouble simply getting VS2017 to run my program in debug mode. The program is a Windows Form Application. I was using it this morning to try to debug the code and it was working fine, except for the bug i was trying to track down, where the code exited without much warning. I was able to step through until the program exited.

The next time i tried to run the code in debug, the screen froze. When it finally recovered, i had this error:

```
'TRAP.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[10804] TRAP.exe' has exited with code -1073741818 (0xc0000006) 'In page error'.
```

It will work fine without debugging and other similar programs work fine with and without debugging.

I have tried:

1. Restarting the computer so there is nothing unexpected running in the background.
2. Re-installing VS2017 community Ed
3. Selecting "Microsoft Symbol Servers" from Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols

   This resulted in this message box that seemed to freeze as well. I never saw any progress made on the progress bar. I cancelled it after about 20 min.
   [image: message box]
4. Setting `<Optimize>false</Optimize>` in the project file as suggested by [Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888343/symbol-status-showing-skipped-loading-for-dll-in-modules-window)
5. Restarting the computer and trying again.

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example? Is the faulting source code short enough to be posted here?

Comment: @vasek, its not a problem with the code, as i was able to run it without debugging. Besides, the code is a bit large, i could give you the github location, but you would still be missing some custom libraries that i couldn't share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug when i created another local repo on my home computer, so i tried re-cloning the repo at work and it has resolved the issue.

I did get an "Alert warning" message box:

```
Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available. Do you want to proceed?
```

After accepting the warning and proceeding, the application seemed to load the necessary PDB files and is working fine now.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, thanks for your sharing. You could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Apparently i need to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer.

Comment: It has two days requirement if you accept it the answer, anyway, thanks for your sharing. You could mark it later.