# Trying to reload project but it says the following error issue IIS web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

The URL 'http:localhost:8081' for Web project 'XXX project name' is configured to use IIS Express as the web server but the URL is currently configured on the local IIS web server. To open this project, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using this URL from the local IIS web server.

It's not allowing me to reload the project..May some thing went wrong while doing IIS set up...

Comment: Here is solution link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284746/web-project-using-iis-but-i-get-error-about-configuration-of-iisexpress/19103452#19103452

Comment: You could also try doing what the error message says: remove that binding (`http://localhost:8081`) from your local IIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2012 can't load project which uses IIS with custom binding host - thinks it's using IIS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657607/vs-2012-cant-load-project-which-uses-iis-with-custom-binding-host-thinks-its)